# tomcat 10 is abruptly getting stopped with springboot3.2.0, jdk 17, mq, kafka and mongo

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, java-17

Server shutdown is happening .. Could you please tell us what is the issue and how to resolve this This is a spring boot application integrated with kafka, mq and mongo database. After upgrading to jdk 17 from jdk 11, server is not responding to http requests. The only solution is to restart the server so that it works fine. below is the exceptions in the logs.

**# **fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment**:**
**# SIGSEGV (oxb) at pc=0x00007f88shdgdhdh, pid=, tid=**
**# JRA Version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.9+11) (build 17.0.9+11-LTS-201)
java VM: Java Hotspot(TM) 64 Bit server VM (17.0.9+11-LTS-201,mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
problematic frames:
JVM crash happened and crash log generated to bin location

Comment: Those warning have nothing to do with the cause, they are shown at shutdown time because something is preventing an orderly shutdown.